# Load Gif image using Kingfisher Swift cause laggy when scrolling down UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, gif, lag

I have a tableview and each cell will load Gif file from server.
I'm using Kingfisher to load Gif file into cell imageview like this:
cell.ivPost?.kf.setImage(with: url)
the Gif is loaded successfully, however the tableview is very laggy when scrolling down. I though that the loading, encode & decode gif file should be done asynchronously using Kingfisher
Anyone has solution for this?

I'm using xCode 8 and Swift 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User this method

```
public func setImage(with resource: Resource?, placeholder: Image? = default, options: KingfisherOptionsInfo? = default, progressBlock: Kingfisher.DownloadProgressBlock? = default, completionHandler: Kingfisher.CompletionHandler? = default) -> Kingfisher.RetrieveImageTask
```

you can give options **KingfisherOptionsInfo**, which is an array of 
**KingfisherOptionsInfoItem**

```
/// Decode the image in background thread before using.
case backgroundDecode
```

Comment: Unrelated, are there any other good options that you like to use?!

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using `SDWebImage` and it works smoothly with `SDAnimatedImageView()`